# synch vs. asynch texture loading in three.js

Tags: asynchronous, three.js, textures

I am have been playing around with Three.js during my lunch hour, implementing the old NEHE demos (up to #30 so far).  One aspect that seems annoying is the new asynchronous texture loaders.  I have a shader material  demo where the material gets created like this:

```js
    var uniforms = {
        tOne: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/cover.png" ) },
        tSec: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/grass.png" ) }
    };
    var material_shh = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: vertShader,
        fragmentShader: fragShader
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeom, material_shh );
    gfxScene.add(mesh);
```

This works fine, but three.js whines at me in the console that `loadTexture` is deprecated. (Why?).  Anyway, I can write it to use a `textureLoader` like this:

```js
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var cover, grass;
    textureLoader.load( "images/cover.png", function( texture ) {
        cover = texture;
    });

    textureLoader.load( "images/grass.png", function( texture ) {
        grass = texture;

       var uniforms = {
            tOne: { type: "t", value: cover  },
            tSec: { type: "t", value: grass  }
        };

        var material_shh = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: vertShader,
            fragmentShader: fragShader
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeom, material_shh );
        gfxScene.add(mesh);
    });
```

This works too, but seems rather convoluted. I get it that async is good for web apps, etc. but... And it assumes that I am guaranteed that the cover.png will be loaded before grass.png.  Is that in fact guaranteed? I'd rather just stick with the synchronous `loadTexture` utility, but perhaps there is a good reason to not use `loadTexture` (other than it is deprecated).  TIA.

Comment: You can load all the resources you need first, using `THREE.LoadingManager()`, and, when all is done, then call the function of animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextureLoader.load()` returns the texture object so if you are not concered about synchronising the loads then you can use the new `TextureLoader` in the same way:

```js
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var uniforms = {
        tOne: {type: "t", value: textureLoader.load("images/cover.png")},
        tSec: {type: "t", value: textureLoader.load("images/grass.png")}
    };
```

**Edit #1**

For a synchronous load you can use the `LoadingManager`. It's not the most elegant API at the moment, but it should work for simple cases. This example is for version `r84`.

```js
function loadTextures(urls, callback) {

    var textures = [];

    var onLoad = function() {
        callback(null, textures);
    };

    var onProgress = function() {};

    var onError = function(url) {
        callback(new Error('Cannot load ' + url));
    };

    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(onLoad, onProgress, onError);

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

    for (var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        textures.push(loader.load(urls[i]));
    }
}

var urls = [
    "images/cover.png",
    "images/grass.png"
];

loadTextures(urls, function(error, textures) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    // Main code goes here using the textures array
});
```

Comment: Ah, that is not mentioned out in the documentation, but if you go read the code itself one can see that.  Thanks.  Reminds me again that with three.js RTFC!

Comment: Oops.  Turns out that this does not always work.  textureLoader always returns a Texture, but sometimes the image is loaded and sometimes it is undefined.  In the latter case, one gets the error:  "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is undefined Texture" from three.js  line 17571 (version 82).  So it looks like I'll have to go back to the "deprecated" method or write convoluted code.  But perhaps I am still missing something.

Comment: Yes, reading the code helps. I've updated the answer with an example to load all textures before running the main code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I guess that is the right way to do it.  It was just much simpler before.  But it is JavaScript and the Web and not C++

Comment: Note, though, that it is even more "convoluted" than this.  If the code which uses the textures is creating a mesh, then you can't use the mesh until it has all executed. This includes any animation that might affect the mesh so created.  Of course you could also put the initial call to animateScene() inside the dependent clause as well.  But now it is getting seriously convoluted (IMHO).  Much simpler if the call to loadTexture were synchronous. Yes, that is blocking, but a small price to pay, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
let urls = [
    'img/right.jpg',//right
    'img/left.jpg',//left
    'img/top.jpg',//top
    'img/top.jpg',//bottom
    'img/front.jpg',//front
    'img/front.jpg',//back
];

function loadTextures(urls) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let textures = [];
        let onLoad = function () {
            resolve(textures);
        };
        let onProgress = function () { };
        let onError = function (url) {
            resolve(false);
        };

        let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(onLoad, onProgress, onError);
        for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            let url = urls[i];
            let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
            textures[i] = loader.load(url);
            console.log('textures 0', textures, url);
        }
    });
}
```

then, inside the init function:

```
let init = async function () {
    let textures = await loadTextures(urls);
    if (textures) {
        let materials = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < textures.length; i++) {
            materials[i] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color: 0xf0f0f0,
                map: textures[i]
            });
        }

        box = new THREE.Mesh(geometryBox, materials);
        scene.add(box);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can see it in action here: https://demo.atelierhexa.com/threejs/box/